# How to read Point(x,y) data from text file using QT?

Tags: c++, qt

Using QT i want to read coordinate values stored in textfile. TextFile will have following content.

```
 80.0910,13.1289
 80.0911,13.1289
 80.0912,13.1290
```

Since these are **GPS values** it will continuously vary over time. so each time i want to read only last value from this file and store it as

> x=80.0912 y=13.1290

This means **i want to split last line and store to x and y.**

I saw similar Question in this forum but nothing satisfies my need to split and store data.

```
QFile inputFile(":/input.txt");
if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
   /* WHAT 
       SHOULD 
          I DO 
             HERE */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your lines always have the same length you could do something like:

```
inputFile.seek(inputFile.size - LENGTH_OF_LINE);
QString line = QString::fromLocal8Bit(inputFile.readLine());
```

or just loop over all lines with QTextStream (this would work with dynamic sized lines):

```
QTextStream ts(inputFile);
QString line;
while(!ts.atEnd())
  line = ts.readLine();
```

EDIT:

For splitting you can use:

```
QStringList list = line.split(",");
double x,y;
if(list.size() == 2)
{
  x = list.at(0).toDouble();
  y = list.at(1).toDouble();
}else{
  qDebug()<<"Line not having coordinates: "<<line;
}
```

EDIT:

Concat both and having a small edit will always produce valid results for last line only, in error produces 0/0 coordinates:

```
QTextStream ts(inputFile);
QString line;
while(!ts.atEnd())
{
  QString temp = ts.readline();
  if(temp.size()>2)
  {
    //having more then 2 chars (e.g. 8,6 as coordinates)
    line = ts.readLine();
  }
}

QStringList list = line.split(",");
double x = 0.0;
double y = 0.0;
if(list.size() == 2)
{
  x = list.at(0).toDouble();
  y = list.at(1).toDouble();
}else{
  qDebug()<<"Line not having coordinates: "<<line;
}
```

Comment: i understand this but my problem is i want to split last line and store to x and y.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It works fine.  how to do this for last line alone.

Comment: @Bavani edited the post to reflect the concatenation, but this should have been easy

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to scan last line:

```
QTextStream stream(inputFile);
QString line;
while(!stream.atEnd())
    line = stream.readLine();

float x, y;
sscanf((char*)line.toAscii().data(), "%2.4f,%2.4f", &x, &y);
```

Comment: i tried your code. when i print x and y it gives 0 as result.